# What is the error with my probability/chance system?

Tags: java

I am currently using a chance system to calculate items.

LootData is a type of object that stores a value to give called an item and chance of obtaining this "item".

An item will contain an ItemStack which is the item as well as a double which is the chance.

It seems as though my math or my code is off since some of the "items" with a low chance are given more frequently.

```
// Calculate total chance
double totalChance = 0;
for (LootData item: items)
    totalChance += item.getChance();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    // Select a 'random chance' from 0 to total chance
    double randomChance = Math.random() * totalChance;

    // Check which item the 'random chance' landed on
    for (LootData item: items) {
        randomChance -= item.getChance();

        if (randomChance < 0) {

            ItemStack stack = item.getItem().clone();
            stack.setAmount((int)(Math.random() * stack.getAmount() + 1));
            itemsToGive.add(stack);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: I think we'll need more information to answer. What types of values are returned by `item.getChance()`? Can you post some sample input and results?

Comment: Also, it seems like the chance is dependent on the order of the `items` list which doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Apologies. So item will contain an ItemStack which is the item as well as a double which is the chance.

Comment: we still need more info, starting from what are you trying to achieve? it's not working, but what would be the expected result, if it was working? what are the values of getChance? Are they normalized to [0,1]? What is the purpose of totalChance?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'll disagree with some of the comments - `getChance()` returns a number, and with the algorithm that you are using it does not matter whether it's `int`, `double`, nor what range, etc.   Nor is the order of items in the list going to affect the results.

I wrapped the code you have supplied with a test loop (with getChance() returning double), but upshot is that I do not see the low-chance items being consistently returned an undue amount.

```
List<LootData> items = Arrays.asList(new LootData(0.1), new LootData(0.1), new LootData(0.4), new LootData(0.3),
    new LootData(0.1)

);
int numberOfItems = 3;

int NUM_TESTS = 100;

// Calculate total chance
double totalChance = 0;
for (LootData item : items)
  totalChance += item.getChance();

for (int testNumber = 0; testNumber < NUM_TESTS; testNumber++) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    // Select a 'random chance' from 0 to total chance
    double randomChance = Math.random() * totalChance;

    // Check which item the 'random chance' landed on
    for (LootData item : items) {
      randomChance -= item.getChance();

      if (randomChance < 0) {
        System.out.println("Selected item " + item + " for " + testNumber + ", " + i);
        item.incrementCount();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

for (LootData item : items) {
  System.out.println(item.getChance() + " count=" + item.getCount() + "  expected="
      + Math.round(NUM_TESTS * numberOfItems * item.getChance() / totalChance));
}
```

Typical result :

```
0.1 count=33  expected=30
0.1 count=24  expected=30
0.4 count=118  expected=120
0.3 count=88  expected=90
0.1 count=37  expected=30
```

Nothing outside expected variability - for example, subsequent runs have the last item return less than 30.

EDIT TO ADD :

Thinking further, although your algorithm above is fine, the problem could be with your expectations and/or how you are building the result list.

I assume you are building your result list to contain unique items - that is, once an item has been added to the ItemStack, it will not be added again.  So with that in mind, let's take an extreme example - 4 really low chance items, and one big-chance item (so 5 total), to return an ItemStack with numberOfItems = 3.

The probability is that that big-chance item will be chosen first.  Once that's happened, that item has ZERO-PROBABILITY of being selected again for that stack.  That means that the low-probability items will be chosen for the remaining 2 slots. 
 Over multiple runs, those low-chance items will be selected many times to fill those remaining slots, so skewing your expected probabilities.

The other consideration is how you ensure uniqueness - what happens if `randomChance` happens to point to big-chance item that has already been selected? 
 Do you simply step onto the next item?   If so, that item inherently becomes more likely to be be selected than any of the other low-chance items - again, skewing the probabilities.   What you need to do is calculate the `totalChance` for each position -  eg, change this :

```
double totalChance = 0;
for (LootData item: items)
    totalChance += item.getChance();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    // Select a 'random chance' from 0 to total chance
    double randomChance = Math.random() * totalChance;

    // Check which item the 'random chance' landed on
    for (LootData item: items) {
        randomChance -= item.getChance();

        if (randomChance < 0) {
```

to this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    double totalChance = 0;
    for (LootData item: items) {
        if (itemsToGive.doesNotInclude(item)) {
            totalChance += item.getChance();
        }
    }

    // Select a 'random chance' from 0 to total chance
    double randomChance = Math.random() * totalChance;

    // Check which item the 'random chance' landed on
    for (LootData item: items) {
        if (itemsToGive.doesNotInclude(item)) {
            randomChance -= item.getChance();

            if (randomChance < 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks alright, and the results seem reasonable.

Maybe, there is a conversion problem?  Switching between different numeric types may be truncating values in unexpected places.

Here is a sample output:

```
Item [  0 ] Freq [   0 ] Odds [ 0.012 ] Proportion [ 0.000 ]
Item [  1 ] Freq [   2 ] Odds [ 0.012 ] Proportion [ 0.020 ]
Item [  2 ] Freq [  14 ] Odds [ 0.122 ] Proportion [ 0.140 ]
Item [  3 ] Freq [  12 ] Odds [ 0.122 ] Proportion [ 0.120 ]
Item [  4 ] Freq [  36 ] Odds [ 0.366 ] Proportion [ 0.360 ]
Item [  5 ] Freq [  36 ] Odds [ 0.366 ] Proportion [ 0.360 ]
```

Here is my write of the algorithm and test code:

```
public class RandomTest {

    public static final int[] lootChance = new int[] { 1, 1, 10, 10, 30, 30 };
    public static final int totalLootChance;
    static {
        int total = 0;
        for ( int chance : lootChance ) {
            total += chance;
        }
        totalLootChance = total;
    }

    public static int lookupItem(double selection) {
        for ( int lootNo = 0; lootNo < lootChance.length; lootNo++ ) {
            selection -= lootChance[lootNo];
            if ( selection < 0 ) {
                return lootNo;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Selection [ " + selection + " ] out of range [ " + totalLootChance + " ]");
    }

    public static final int lootRuns = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Items [ %2d ] Weighed Total [ %3d ]\n", lootChance.length, totalLootChance);
        for ( int itemNo = 0; itemNo < lootChance.length; itemNo++) {
            System.out.printf("  [ %2d ] [ %3d ]\n", itemNo, lootChance[itemNo]);
        }

        int[] distribution = new int[ lootChance.length ];

        for ( int runNo = 0; runNo < lootRuns; runNo++ ) {
            double selection = Math.random() * totalLootChance;
            int itemSelection = lookupItem(selection);
            distribution[itemSelection]++;

            System.out.printf(
                "Run [ %3s ] Roll [ %04.2f ] Item [ %2d ]\n",
                runNo, selection, itemSelection);
        }

        for ( int lootNo = 0; lootNo < lootChance.length; lootNo++ ) {
            System.out.printf(
                "Item [ %2d ] Freq [ %3d ] Odds [ %02.3f ] Proportion [ %02.3f ]\n",
                lootNo,
                distribution[lootNo],
                (((double) lootChance[lootNo]) / totalLootChance),
                ((double) distribution[lootNo]) / lootRuns);
        }
    }
}
```